# Binary compatibility between ARM Cortex A7 and A9

Tags: linux, gcc, arm

I tried to google but I could only find info about A15-A7 full compatibility, forward and backward.
Currently I have a task to build binaries for Cortex-a9, but I have no hardware to test them on, therefore I was thinking to test them on Cortex-a7 dev board, therefore **the question**:

Can I build code with `-mcpu=cortex-a9` and run the resulting binary on a system where libc, libstdc++ and other binaries were built with `-mcpu=cortex-a7`? Is this compatible in both directions?

Let's assume that all binaries (mine and target runtime) are built with `-mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard`.

Comment: maybe you can use [qemu](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms/ARM) instead? shows it supports the [ARM926](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0198/e/introduction/about-the-arm926ej-s-processor)

Comment: both are armv7-a but there are chip specific options, so you have to check with the specific chip vendor.  no reason to assume that all cortex-a7s are equal to each other much less a cortex-a9...

Comment: With gcc, you can use '-march=armv7-a` (with fp/simd extras).  You can not write kernel level code that is compatible without conditionals; so you can have a 'basic block' for each but this will not be 'testable'.  If you want to 'optimize' for the cortex-a9, use `-mtune=cortex-a9`. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html#ARM-Options  The ABI is another question.  You can build -mcpu=cortex-a9 and it will not work if the ABI is not correct.  For instance, hard-float versus soft-float, etc.  You need to know what libc they use.  For instance Debian binaries don't work on Android.